# Magento 2 : Best practice to load category EAV value

Tags: category, eav, category-attribute, m2e

I want to know what is best practice to load a complex EAV attribute in a block. I have added a custom EAV attribute to category and I can see it in Catelog_Category_Entity_Text table, although I am not able to access it via, Category->getResource->getAttribute method.

Thanks in Advance.